# Koma-script tikz \lehead book separators

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, koma-script

I am using the Koma-Script scrbook document class. I would like to print an tikz image in the left-top heading of all even pages, but the figure gets shifted toward the right at every new page,so that at page 206, the figure is already half way inside the text.

See page 2 [image: Page number 2] and compare to page 206 [image: page number 206]

Does anyone has a clue why the image doesn't stay at the intended position?. Here is the code to explain in more detail my issue:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[automark, headsepline]{scrpage2}

\usepackage{lipsum}
% Place the page number and a black square in a fix position
\lehead{\thepage \tikz[overlay, remember picture]\fill [black] ($(-0.2,-1)$) rectangle ($(-1.2,-2)$);}

% Default page style
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the order of the commands: You wrote `\thepage \tikz...`, which will insert a number and then the rectangle. As the pagenumber increases, this number gets more digits. So the problem is that e.g. *206* is wider than *6*. It works fine if you reverse the order. Also, using `\thepage` may cause problems, as due to shifting floats around it sometimes may not contain the actual pagenumber. It's better to use `\pagemark` here.

### Code

```
\documentclass{scrbook}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[automark, headsepline]{scrpage2}

\usepackage{lipsum}
% Place the page number and a black square in a fix position
\lehead{\tikz[overlay, remember picture]{\fill [black] (-0,-1) rectangle ++(-1,-1);} \pagemark}

% Default page style
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\lipsum[3-56]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: There is no need for the `remember picture` option (at least in the given example). Removing the option also saves us one line per TikZ picture in the `.aux` file.

Comment: Ah, of cause. Didn't even look at that ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the tikz syntax, but playing with the values helps:

```
\lehead{\thepage \tikz[overlay, remember picture]\fill [black] ($(-0.4,1)$) rectangle ($(-1.2,-0.2)$);}
```